# inserting values into mysql table using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Values inserted using program are not seen in database. the following is the code which I used for the same

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class JDBC {

    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("hii");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rsystems", "root", "rsystems");
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into user valiues(?,?)");
        System.out.println("Enter id:");
        int no = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        String name = sc.next();
        stmt.setInt(1, no);
        stmt.setString(2, name);
        //I think I need to commit over here and I have tried the same but even with that I didn't see my inserted data in database
    }

}
```

Comment: You never execute your statement.

Comment: `valiues`.....?  It's also usually a better idea to specify the order of the columns, something like `insert into user (id, name) values (?, ?)`.  Have a closer look at [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You've wrong query in your `PreparedStatement`

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into user (id, name) values(?,?)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You query is wrong and you are never executing it.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into user values(?,?)");
stmt.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing your query inside preparedStatement. Also make sure you have valid SQL.

You can use [`PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29)

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

Try

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into user values(?,?)");
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

---

From maintenance point of view, we specify order of columns in insert query like.

```
insert into user (id, name) values(?,?)
```

---

**Commit:**

You can check your database configuration about autoCommit. If by default autoCommit is true then you can omit commiting in your code else you will have to commit it manually in your code. Like

```
con.commit();
```

---

**Connection close:**

You should close your statements and connection when they are no longer required.

```
stmt.close();
connection.close();
```

---

**Note:** Don't forget to handle/throw Exceptions throws from all these methods such as [`SQLException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use try..catch help you to find the mistake you make just a wrong word

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root";
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);

            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected");
            }

            String sql = "INSERT INTO Users (id, password,) VALUES (?, ?)";

            PreparedStatement statement;
            statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setInt(1, 1);
            statement.setString(2, "admin");

            int rowsInserted = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (rowsInserted > 0) {
                System.out.println("A Record inserted successfully!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured" + e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting value need PreparedStatement executed
Look at below

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JDBC {

    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("hii");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rsystems", "root", "rsystems");
        PreparedStatement stmt = con
                .prepareStatement("insert into user valiues(?,?)");
        System.out.println("Enter id:");
        int no = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        String name = sc.next();
        stmt.setInt(1, no);
        stmt.setString(2, name);
        stmt.execute();//You have to execute this statement
        // I think I need to commit over here and I have tried the same but even
        // with that I didn't see my inserted data in database
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class JDBC {

private static Scanner sc;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("hii");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rsystems", "root", "rsystems");
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into user values(?,?)");
    System.out.println("Enter id:");
    int no = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter name:");
    String name = sc.next();
    stmt.setInt(1, no);
    stmt.setString(2, name);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

}